# how to check something eg java, php, program etc installed with python?

Tags: python

im makeing something like a check system before run so it meets the requirements with python.
heres my code so far;

```
def checksystem():
    installednode = os.popen('node ' + srctocoffeecompiler + ' -v')
    // version 1.1.1
    print installednode.read()
```

i can print the version but **is there a better way to check its installed with a version higher then 1.0.x** ? heres my code so far to do this.

```
version = installednode.read()
if installednode.read() == 'CoffeeScript version 1.1.1':
    // the code
    // or split the string with space then get the last array
    // check if its more then 1.1.1 or 111 ( dots removed )
```

*edit ive read the docs about useing subprocess.Popen, that is maybe better, not sure. im still geting errors *no such file exist*.

*edit2

```
pn = subprocess.Popen(['node','-v'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
print "NodeJS version: " + pn.read()
```

ok, somehow i can call it, but i cant read its output return, same with java

```
pj = subprocess.Popen(['java','-version'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
print "JAVA: " + pj.read()
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the version string, the comparison is pretty simple if you use lists:

```
>>> vers1 = '1.0.1'.split('.')
>>> vers2 = '1.0.0'.split('.')
>>> vers1
['1', '0', '1']
>>> vers2
['1', '0', '0']
>>> vers1 > vers2
True
>>> vers2 > vers1
False
>>>
```

Here's a JavaScript alternative:

```
>>> var vers1 = "1.0.1".split('.');
>>> var vers2 = "1.0.0".split('.');
>>> vers1
["1", "0", "1"]
>>> vers2
["1", "0", "0"]
>>> vers1 > vers2
true
>>> vers2 > vers1
false
```

It's pretty much the same ;-)

Comment: python is really showing off. :D thanks, i never know we can do this well not in php without a function i guess.

Comment: well im still haveing a problem returning rather then outputing the `-v`, it should be returned to `installednode` so there is nothing on the screen, instead it will be in `installednode = 'CoffeeScript version 1.1.1'`

Comment: Which Python version do you use? os.popen() is deprecated. You should use `subprocess`.

Comment: updated, yup im using it right now, new problems, i cant even get the return version.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(['java','-version'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).stderr.read()`

Comment: @Fabian let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2156/discussion-between-adam-ramadhan-and-fabian)